# angularJS check ng-repeat with ng-if alternately

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

i have this UI arrange in this kind of order:

```
AM   |   PM
AM   |   PM
AM   |   PM
AM   |   PM
```

but my JSON is in this order: {AM, AM, AM, AM, PM, PM, PM, PM}

i've tried to use ng-repeat and ng-if (you may see the code below) but unfortunately it loaded like this:

```
AM    |    AM   |  (note: Am has right border)
AM    |    AM   |
PM         PM
PM         PM
```

here is my code:

```
<div class="row main">
   <div  ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts" class="column-left">
     <div ng-if="forecast.hour.indexOf('AM') !== -1" class="row">
          //here will be the AM
     </div>
     <hr>
   </div> 
   <div ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts" class="column-right">
      <div ng-if="forecast.hour.indexOf('PM') !== -1" class="row">
         //here will be the PM                          
      </div>
      <hr>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: i've tried to seperate the ng-repeat so that it wont mix up but still it fails. just like that i combine it with single ng-repeat.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you create a plunker or fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.forecasts = ['AM', 'AM', 'AM', 'AM', 'PM', 'PM', 'PM', 'PM']
}])
```

```css
.column {
 width: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.am {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <section ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <div class="row main">
      
      <div  class="column column-left">
        <div ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts track by $index" ng-if="forecast == 'AM'" class="am" ng-bind="::forecast"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div  class="column column-right">
        <div ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts track by $index" ng-if="forecast == 'PM'" class="pm" ng-bind="::forecast"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/2shpNUJBCHbrjW3HpgZM?p=preview)?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div  ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts" ng-if="forecast.time === 'AM'">
       {{forecast}}
       <hr>
      </div> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <div  ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts" ng-if="forecast.time === 'PM'">
       {{forecast}}
       <hr>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it seems to me, that this is not the best way.